# Search complexity of redisearch FT.SEARCH?

Tags: redis, redisearch

Their document below says it is O(n), without specifying what n is there. If it is no of documents in the index then search can be extremely slow. This doesn't make any sense, or does it ?

https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Commands.html#complexity_6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

n is the number of the results in the result set, basically finding all the documents that have a specific term is O(1), then a scan on all those documents is needed to load the documents data from redis hashes and return them.